Beginner level JSON and Render.com issue regarding builds
I have no experience with JSON but I've been left to decipher and update a script that was handed to me.
I will be as detailed as I can since I'm not sure at all at what level is my error.
I have uploaded a script from my GitHub to render.com.
My GitHub files:

This is what is contained in the package.json:
{
  "name": "list-upload",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
      "node": "20.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}

Now when on render.com, it seems to build fine with something called Yarn.

However I then get to this Error regarding engines and extensions.

And then when I try to reach the index.html, it tells me either there is an Internal Server Error or Cannot GET /index.html.
My Google searches haven't been very fruitful unfortunately, so any help would be appreciated. For more context: the HTML has a form on it and the server.js has the keys required to post to an API and upload the info from the form.
Edit:
Here is a shortened version of server.js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors') // for development only
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
const port = 3000 // adjust port number if needed

const apiKeys = {
  presidentkey: 'xxxxxxx',
  communcationDinternalkey: 'xxxxxxx'
}

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen('9000');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {})
})

app.post('/get-lists', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const Name = req.body.Name
    const Account = req.body.Accountid

    let selectedApiKey
    if (Account === 582045) {
      selectedApiKey = apiKeys.presidentkey
    }
    if (Account === 578195) {
      selectedApiKey = apiKeys.communcationDinternalkey
    }
  

    const response = await fetch('https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Lists/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        ApiKey: selectedApiKey,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Name,
      }),
    })

    const data = await response.json()

    res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching data from Campaigner API' })
  }
})

app.post('/get-emails', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const Emails = req.body.emailsList
    const ListID = req.body.listid
    const accountID = req.body.accountno
    console.log(Emails)
    console.log(ListID)
    console.log(accountID)

    let selectedApiKeyEmails
    if (accountID === 582045) {
      selectedApiKeyEmails = apiKeys.presidentkey
    }
    if (accountID === 578195) {
      selectedApiKeyEmails = apiKeys.communcationDinternalkey
    }

    const subscriberData2 = {
      EmailAddresses: Emails,
    }

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Lists/${ListID}/AddEmails`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',

          ApiKey: selectedApiKeyEmails,
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(subscriberData2),
      }
    )

    const data = await response.json()

    res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching data from Campaigner API' })
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
})

And this is the html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Campaigner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Campaigner List Upload</h1>
  <form autocomplete="off" id="campaigner-form">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="582045" name="List2" value="OOP" />
      <label for="582045">582045 Office of the President</label><br />
      <input type="checkbox" id="582065" name="List4" value="Coms" />
      <label for="582065">582065 Communications Directorate (External)</label>
    </div>
    <label for="name">List Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
    <label for="fileUpload">Upload Excel Files:</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".xlsx" multiple /><br />
    <strong>Excel file must contain a column with a header named "Email"</strong><br />
    <label for="itemnumber" id="itemnumber"></label><br />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <div id="progressBarContainer">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p class="waiting"></p>
  <p class="upload-status-name"></p>
  <p class="upload-status-data"></p>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xlsx@0.16.8/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-Ic7HP804IrYks4vUqX1trFF1Nr33RjONeJESZnYxsOY="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    const uploadName = document.querySelector('.upload-status-name')
    const uploadData = document.querySelector('.upload-status-data')
    const waitingmessage = document.querySelector('.waiting')
    const listOfEmails = []
    const form = document.getElementById('campaigner-form')
    const fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload')

    function splitLargeArray(data) {
      if (data.length <= 1000) {
        return [data]
      }
      const subArrays = []
      let remaining = data
      while (remaining.length) {
        const chunk = remaining.slice(0, 1000)
        subArrays.push(chunk)
        remaining = remaining.slice(1000)
      }
      return subArrays
    }

    async function getData(accountid) {
      const listname = document.getElementById('name').value
      const myHeaders = new Headers()
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      const raw = JSON.stringify({
        Name: listname,
        Accountid: accountid,
      })
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow',
      }
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://campaigner.onrender.com/get-lists',
          requestOptions
        )
        const result = await response.text()
        const list = JSON.parse(result).ListID
        const concat = `${result}`.split(',')
        console.log(result)
        uploadData.innerHTML = `List Uploaded: ${concat[1]}`
        splitLargeArray(listOfEmails).forEach((element) => {
          getEmails(element, list, accountid)
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }

    async function getEmails(emailsList, listid, accountno) {
      const myHeaders = new Headers()
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      const raw = JSON.stringify({
        emailsList,
        listid,
        accountno,
      })
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow',
      }
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://campaigner.onrender.com/get-emails',
          requestOptions
        )
        const result = await response.text()
        console.log(result)
        waitingmessage.innerHTML = ''
        uploadName.innerHTML = result
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        uploadName.innerHTML = error
      }
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
      const accountsarray = []
      waitingmessage.innerHTML = 'Uploading contacts...'
      for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          accountsarray.push(parseInt(checkbox.id))
        }
      }
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(accountsarray)
      accountsarray.forEach((element) => {
        getData(element)
      })
    })

    const emailCountLabel = document.getElementById('itemnumber')

    fileUpload.addEventListener('change', function () {
      const selectedFiles = fileUpload.files
      if (selectedFiles.length === 0) {
        return
      }
      const emailList = []
      let emailCount = 0

      for (const file of selectedFiles) {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function (event) {
          const data = event.target.result
          const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' })
          const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]
          const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName]
          const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 })
          emailCount += jsonData.length - 1

          workbook.SheetNames.forEach((sheet) => {
            const result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet], {
              raw: false,
            })
            result.forEach((element) => {
              if ('email' in element) {
                listOfEmails.push(element.email)
              } else if ('Email' in element) {
                listOfEmails.push(element.Email)
              } else {
                listOfEmails.push(element.Subscribers)
              }
            })
          })
          console.log(listOfEmails)
          const formattedEmails = emailList.join('<br>')
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
      }
      emailCountLabel.innerHTML = `Total emails: ${emailCount}`
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I think if you don't post the code, it will be difficult for people to understand or help.
